# Why can't I POST data using Express?

Tags: node.js, express

```
var locationJSON, locationRequest;
locationJSON = {
  latitude: 'mylat',
  longitude: 'mylng'
};
locationRequest = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 1234,
  path: '/',
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content-length': locationJSON.length
  }
};

var req;
req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  var body;
  body = '';
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });
  return res.on('end', function() {
    console.log(body);
    callback(null, body);
  });
});
req.on('error', function(err) {
  callback(err);
});
req.write(data);
req.end();
```

On the other end, I have a node.js server listening to port 1234 and it never gets the request. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like `req.write` requires a string, array or buffer. So maybe I should convert my JSON to an array?

Comment: Run it through JSON.stringify() and set the Content-Type to be application/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `req.write(data)` but as far as I can see 'data' is not defined anywhere. You are also setting the 'content-length' header to locationJSON.length, which is undefined because locationJSON only has 'latitude' and 'longitude' properties.

Properly define 'data', and change the 'content-type' and 'content-length' to use that instead.

```
var locationJSON, locationRequest;
locationJSON = {
  latitude: 'mylat',
  longitude: 'mylng'
};

// convert the arguments to a string
var data = JSON.stringify(locationJSON);

locationRequest = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 1234,
  path: '/',
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
    'content-type': 'application/json', // Set the content-type to JSON
    'content-length': data.length       // Use proper string as length
  }
};

/*
....
*/

req.write(data, 'utf8');  // Specify proper encoding for string
req.end();
```

Let me know if this still doesn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to set the Content-Type to application/json and then do req.write(JSON.stringify(data));?

Comment: He didn't specify how his server was set up, so I didn't want to go changing too many things, but yeah if the server can decode arguments with content-type application/json that would work too.

Comment: The title of the post says Express, and he is using no functionality from Express in his example; So, I assume the server receiving the request is Express. It's bodyParser middleware supports decoding of application/json and placing the information in req.body.